# Fast way to approximate $U_1 X_1 U_1^T$ + $U_2 X_2 U_2^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $n \times n$ symetric matrix $X_1, X_2, $ and $m \times n$ matrices  $U_1, U_2$, where $m \gg  n$

Such that
$$U_1 X_1 U_1^T \approx U_2 X_2 U_2^T$$
and
$$X_1 \approx X_2$$

I want to find $n' \times n'$ matrix $X$ and $m \times n'$ matrix $U$ such that

$$U X U^T \approx U_1 X_1 U_1^T + U_2 X_2 U_2^T
, n' \leq 2n$$

Is it possible without evaluating the whole sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach would be to use QR and Singular value decompositions.
Your sum can be expressed via $$\begin{bmatrix}U_1 & U_2\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}X_1 & 0 \\ 0 & X_2\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}U_1^T \\ U_2^T\end{bmatrix}. $$
Write $ U_0 = \begin{bmatrix}U_1 &U_2\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 2n}$ and calculate the QR-Decomposition of that (factors $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 2n}$ and $R\in \mathbb{R}^{2n \times 2n}$).
You then find $U_S$ and $S$ as singular values and singular vectors of $$R \cdot \begin{bmatrix}X_1 & 0 \\ 0 & X_2\end{bmatrix}R^T$$ ($V_S$ is eequal to $U_S$ due to symmetry) and have your final sum as
$$(Q U_S) \cdot S \cdot (U_S^TQ^T). $$

You can also reduce the inner rank of your sum by choosing which singular values of the product to keep and which to discard.

Generally, you will end up with a matrix of rank $2n$, but in practice, this rank can (and will) be much smaller.

This algorithm is used in the addition of [H-matrices](https://www.mis.mpg.de/scicomp/Fulltext/WS_HMatrices.pdf).